# Node.js com vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express.js

Node e vuejs podem se complementar ? É normal usar vuejs, node.js e espressJS em conjunto ?

Na minha visão são 3 frameworks diferentes, mas faz sentido usá-los juntos ?

Comment: Ué, um não tem nada a ver com o outro **Vue** é um framework **Js** que atua no Front-end, ou seja, você pode utilizar qualquer coisa no back-end, Java, C#, Php, Nodejs, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim.
Gerencia o front com VUE, e o back com o node/express.